# Authentication with openid.stackexchange.com fails with firefox

Tags: support, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid, authentication

Since todays morning, I got an exception, if I like to login to any stackexchange site using openid.stackexchange.com with Firefox. (It works with Chrome ...)

I can login to openid.stackexchange.com:

[image]

But authorizing to some site fails with the following exception:

Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

> The openid.return_to parameter
>   (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/?s=cb9378cb-8570-4064-bfb7-0ecfe0835985&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid)
>   does not match the actual URL
>   (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/?s=cb9378cb-8570-4064-bfb7-0ecfe0835985&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2014-01-06T21%3A26%3A55ZHBQge5OPU0lAqQ&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2Fauthenticate%2F%3Fs%3Dcb9378cb-8570-4064-bfb7-0ecfe0835985%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid&openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9VOKtHgXkMyzJC5xQYgaAqS97oZvX-bHFsH7MAh7LzpudRC62QnNH8Jxs5s&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.alias4%2Cext1.value.alias4&openid.sig=mFkKhm%2F9TxJI29t8tfUpOriUKk4%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawnUcXhrmiZrJ1xYGLoQwm4UoEv_C592ocM&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawnUcXhrmiZrJ1xYGLoQwm4UoEv_C592ocM&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.alias4=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.alias4=mail%40thomas-kuhlmann.de)
>   the request was made with.

Comment: tl;dr: disable HTTPSEverywhere, or disable the rule that causes this.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks. That's it.